# created a slider for testimonial, but the width slides horizonal

Tags: html, css

The below code for testimonial slider has created an unwanted horizontal scroll bar due to the the width. If I reduced the width from the CSS file, the other testimonial comes together which I do not wanted, as the bar at the bottom when clicked slides to the testimonial. I think it's the slide-col width that is creating the problem, is there a way I can hide the other testimonial and when I click on the bar, the testimonial appears/slides.

```js
var test__btn = document.getElementsByClassName("test__btn");
var slide = document.getElementById("slide");

test__btn[0].onclick = function() {
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    test__btn[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
};
test__btn[1].onclick = function() {
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(-800px)";
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    test__btn[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
};
test__btn[2].onclick = function() {
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(-1600px)";
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    test__btn[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
};
test__btn[3].onclick = function() {
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(-2400px)";
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    test__btn[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
};
```

```css
/*-----Testimonial-------*/

.testimonial-main {
  background: var(--color-primary);
  height: 120vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(117, 94, 94, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.testimonial-sub {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.testimonial__container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -15%;
}

.test__btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: var(--color-secondary);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  width: 45px;
}

.slide-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 3200px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.slide-col {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.user-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 330px;
  height: 100%;
}

.user-img img {
  height: 30%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.user-text {
  background: #2d3a59;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
  top: 220px;
  transform: translateY(-25%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #d3d4d6;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}

.user-text p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.user-text h3 {
  margin: 35px 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}


/* ------testimonial  close-------*/
```

```html
<!--Testimonial-->
<section id="testimonial">
  <div>
    <h1 class="heading__h1" data-aos="zoom-in-left">
      WHAT OUR CUSTOMERS SAY ABOUT US
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonial-main">
    <div class="testimonial__container">
      <div class="indicator">
        <span class="test__btn active">1</span>
        <span class="test__btn">2</span>
        <span class="test__btn">3</span>
        <span class="test__btn">4</span>
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial-sub">
        <div class="slide-row" id="slide">
          <div class="slide-col">
            <div class="user-text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate explicabo minima earum recusandae, neque facilis mollitia sunt asperiores eos.
              </p>
              <h3>Client 1</h3>
              <p>Company 1 LTD</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user-img">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-col">
            <div class="user-text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate explicabo minima earum recusandae, neque facilis mollitia sunt asperiores eos.
              </p>
              <h3>Client 2</h3>
              <p>Company 2 LTD</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user-img">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-col">
            <div class="user-text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate explicabo minima earum recusandae, neque facilis mollitia sunt asperiores eos.
              </p>
              <h3>Client 3</h3>
              <p>Company 3 LTD</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user-img">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-col">
            <div class="user-text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate explicabo minima earum recusandae, neque facilis mollitia sunt asperiores eos.
              </p>
              <h3>Client 4</h3>
              <p>Company 4 LTD</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user-img">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HTML:
<!--Testimonial-->
    <div>
      <h1 class="heading__h1" data-aos="zoom-in-left">
        WHAT OUR CUSTOMERS SAY ABOUT US
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-container" id="testimonial">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg"
          alt=""
          class="slide__img"
        />
        <p>
          Many people feel that there is a limited amount of abundance, wealth,
          or chance to succeed in life. Furthermore, there is a solid beleif
          that if one person succeeds, another must fail.
        </p>
        <h3>Riley Olie</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg"
          alt=""
          class="slide__img"
        />
        <p>
          Many people feel that there is a limited amount of abundance, wealth,
          or chance to succeed in life. Furthermore, there is a solid beleif
          that if one person succeeds, another must fail.
        </p>
        <h3>Steve McCurry</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg"
          alt=""
          class="slide__img"
        />
        <p>
          Many people feel that there is a limited amount of abundance, wealth,
          or chance to succeed in life. Furthermore, there is a solid beleif
          that if one person succeeds, another must fail.
        </p>
        <h3>Merlin Nguyen</h3>
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div style="text-align: center" class="dot__group">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>

css:
/* Testimonial */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 115vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
}

.slide__img {
  width: 15rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 55px;
  color: #fff;
}

.mySlides p::before {
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.mySlides p::after {
  content: "\201D";
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.mySlides h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.dot__group {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 6rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.active {
  width: 45px !important;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* ------testimonial  close-------*/

js:
 <!--Testimonial slider-->
    <script>
      var slideIndex = 1;
      showSlides(slideIndex);

      function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides((slideIndex += n));
      }

      function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides((slideIndex = n));
      }

      function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 1;
        }
        if (n < 1) {
          slideIndex = slides.length;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have not used CSS well which make it overflow it's container

```js
var test__btn = document.getElementsByClassName("test__btn");
var slide = document.getElementById("slide");

test__btn[0].onclick = function() {
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    test__btn[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
};
test__btn[1].onclick = function() {
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(-100vw)";
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    test__btn[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
};
test__btn[2].onclick = function() {
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(-200vw)";
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    test__btn[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
};
test__btn[3].onclick = function() {
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(-300vw)";
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    test__btn[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
};
```

```css
/*-----Testimonial-------*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.testimonial-main {
  background: var(--color-primary);
  height: auto;
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(117, 94, 94, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.testimonial-sub {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.testimonial__container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding:50px;
  background-color:red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
}


.slide-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 400vw;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.slide-col {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  position:relative;
  left:-200px;
  display:block;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color:green
}

.user-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 330px;
  height: 100%;
}

.user-img img {
  height: 30%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.user-text {
  background: #2d3a59;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
  top: 220px;
  transform: translateY(-25%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #d3d4d6;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}

.user-text p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.user-text h3 {
  margin: 35px 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -15%;
}

.test__btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: var(--color-secondary);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  width: 45px;
}



/* ------testimonial  close-------*/
```

```html
<!--Testimonial-->
<section id="testimonial">
  <div>
    <h1 class="heading__h1" data-aos="zoom-in-left">
      WHAT OUR CUSTOMERS SAY ABOUT US
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonial-main">
    <div class="testimonial__container">
      <div class="indicator">
        <span class="test__btn active">1</span>
        <span class="test__btn">2</span>
        <span class="test__btn">3</span>
        <span class="test__btn">4</span>
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial-sub">
        <div class="slide-row" id="slide">
          <div class="slide-col">
            <div class="user-text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate explicabo minima earum recusandae, neque facilis mollitia sunt asperiores eos.
              </p>
              <h3>Client 1</h3>
              <p>Company 1 LTD</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user-img">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-col">
            <div class="user-text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate explicabo minima earum recusandae, neque facilis mollitia sunt asperiores eos.
              </p>
              <h3>Client 2</h3>
              <p>Company 2 LTD</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user-img">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-col">
            <div class="user-text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate explicabo minima earum recusandae, neque facilis mollitia sunt asperiores eos.
              </p>
              <h3>Client 3</h3>
              <p>Company 3 LTD</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user-img">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-col">
            <div class="user-text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate explicabo minima earum recusandae, neque facilis mollitia sunt asperiores eos.
              </p>
              <h3>Client 4</h3>
              <p>Company 4 LTD</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user-img">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8x9xK4H/team.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello Rana, thank you for your response, unfortunately, I have tried the snippet of the code, but still doesn't work correctly. The code above I used from watching a youtube video.

Comment: Thats the reason making a small change in CSS of one element makes huge changes in other

Comment: I am not sure what the error or change I have made as I copied code by code and still does not work.

Comment: Hi Rana, thanks for your help, I got it working now.

Comment: Can you share it as a answer here plz

Comment: yes sure, off course